# Calling API inside the loop using php

Tags: php, loops, curl, while-loop

I looking for any best and fastest way to call API inside the loop for example bellow is my current code but I don't think that is the good way because in this way API is being called 100s of time because it's under the php loop. Is there anyway I can use it outside ? but the problem is I have to pass some unique values which are only in loop.

```
$sql_q = sqlsrv_query($mssql, "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Club='123'");
   while($sql_f = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_q)){
        
    / Calling API TO Check Status
    $auth = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($auth, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.checkstatus.com/apiurl",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n  <soap:Body>\r\n    <CheckStatus xmlns=\"http://apiurl.info/\">\r\n      <UserID>".$ql_f['ID']."</UserID>\r\n </CheckStatus >\r\n  </soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: text/xml"
    ),
    ));
    $authres = curl_exec($auth);
    curl_close($auth);
    
    }
```

Comment: why do you have to submit so many? it will likely refuse your requests at some point.

Comment: Are you sure about `while($sql_f = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_q)){`

Comment: It depends on what the API supports. I don't see any way around sending a lot of requests if your API only supports this parameterization.

Comment: while loop is working fine even API also working fine but my concern is about loading speed and I am pretty sure that is because I am calling API inside the loop. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Usually API's has some-kind of a filtering, my advice is to check the documentation of the API you're using and fetch all the data you need with 1 request or couple of requests(using offset, page or whatever)... What if you get 2000 records from the database? You'll make 2000 requests to the API ? This doesn't seems right at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a scheduling mechanism

For example:

1. Create a queue of IDs to be passed to the API (a MySQL table would do)
2. Write a script that takes the first item from the queue and makes the API call.
3. After the call, remove the ID from the queue or mark it as done
4. Use e.g. cron to schedule how often the script gets called
5. Create another script that manages the queue according to your business logic

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am calling API to check status but not to update status so cron job won't help I guess.

Comment: In other words I am displaying a list of users and with their status. and Status coming from the API so whenever I run this code I want to see all the users with their statuses instead of waiting for the cron job.

Comment: How about checking the status asynchronously and displaying the last known status in the user list? If a status check is an expensive operation you should find ways to minimize the use of it. e.g. by caching statuses locally, updating status upon specific request, creating another API that can return statuses in bulk, etc.